# Static variables were getting null values in continuation method

Tags: apex

I have one class as follows:

```
global class myclass {
    public static var1;
    public static var2;
    public static var3;
    public static someotherclass.method var4;

    @RemoteAction
    global static Object continuationmethod(string par1,id par2,boolean par3){
        var4='test';
        var1='test1';
        var2='test2';
    }

    //call back method for continuation method
    public static Object callbackmethod(Object State){

    }
}
```

Now I want to use the `var1`, `var2` and `var3` values in callback method. But I was getting null values. How to overcome this issue? Can anyone suggest one solution?

Comment: Unlike Java, Apex static classes keep state only during one request. A new request will have new state. I hope you are accessing the callbackmethod during the same request as continuationmethod.

Answer (score 11):

Static variables are effectively [transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm), meaning they don't remember their state between transactions on a Visualforce page. This is doubly important since continuation methods are, by definition, not tied to the view state.

Instead, you need to store your state, as shown in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm):

```
// Declare inner class to hold state info
private class StateInfo {
    String msg { get; set; }
    List<String> urls  { get; set; }
    StateInfo(String msg, List<String> urls) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}

// Then in the action method, set state for the continuation
continuationInstance.state = new StateInfo('Some state data', urls);
```

In other words, you simply need to set the `state` variable, which can be any serialized data; your callback method accepts one parameter of type Object, which you can then cast back in to a myclass variable to access the parameters.

Also see [Apex Continuations: Asynchronous Callouts from Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/02/apex-continuations-asynchronous-callouts-visualforce-pages.html) for an example:

```
// Called via JavaScript Remoting
@RemoteAction
public static Object callService(Integer count){
    // Make an HTTPRequest as we normally would
    // Remember to configure a Remote Site Setting for the service!
    String url = 'https://node-count.herokuapp.com/'+count;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint(url);

    // Create a Continuation for the HTTPRequest       
    Continuation con = new Continuation(60);
    con.state = con.addHttpRequest(req);
    con.continuationMethod = 'callback';       

    // Return it to the system for processing
    return con;
}

public static Object callback(Object state) {
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse((String)state);

    Integer statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode >= 2000) {
        return 'Continuation error: ' + errors.get(statusCode);
    }

    return response.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `Continuation` class contains a state property (of type `Object`) that allows you to store and the retrieve data during the callback.

If you are making an HTTP request, then create a wrapper object:

```
public class MyWrapper {

    public String Request { get; set; }
    public String Variable1 { get; set; }
    public String Variable2 { get; set; }

    public MyWrapper(String req, String var1, String var2) {
        Request = req;
        Variable1 = var1;
        Variable2 = var2;
    }
}
```

Then use the wrapper in the continuation:

```
@RemoteAction
public static Object callService(Integer count){

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('http://rest-api.com');

    Continuation con = new Continuation(60);

    MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(con.addHttpRequest(req), 'test1', 'test2');
    con.state = wrapper;
    con.continuationMethod = 'callback';        

    return con;
}

public static Object callback(Object state) {

    MyWrapper wrapper = (MyWrapper)state;
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(wrapper.Request);

    String var1 = wrapper.Variable1;
    String var2 = wrapper.Variable2;

    Integer statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode >= 2000) {
        return 'Continuation error: ' + errors.get(statusCode);
    }

    return response.getBody();
}
```

Comment: i am not using the http request , i am using the soap

Comment: I'd hope given the above code that you would understand the pattern required and adapt it for your implementation.

Comment: I am getting an error like con.state variable does not exist